# Using Context, can I (programiatically) move the page's menu to a different region?

Tags: 7

Using Context, can I move a node's menu to a different region?

Or more specifically, from inside `hook_context_page_reaction()`, can I get access to the page's render array to move items between regions?

I'm working with this below.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_context_page_reaction().
 */
function context_movemenu_context_page_reaction()
{

    $node = node_load(menu_get_object()->nid);
    if ($plugin = context_get_plugin('reaction', 'context_movemenu')) {
         $plugin->execute();
    }
}
```

and using this execute() method. I'm just dumping all incoming args to see what I can send over.

```
function execute() {
   dpm(func_get_args());
}
```

Am I approaching this from the wrong location? Ideally, this sites has most of it's configuration in context. The site owner likes that workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place ***all*** blocks in template_preprocess_page with

```
$variables['page'][$region_key] = array();
$variables['page'][$region_key][]['#markup'] = $region_content;
```

Seeing your edit, you can check for the plugins blocks like this

```
$context_content_bottom = array();
  $blocks_content_bottom = array();

  // Blocks that are assigned to the region using Context
  if ($plugin = context_get_plugin('reaction', 'block')) {
    $context_content_bottom = $plugin->block_get_blocks_by_region('content_bottom');
  }

  // Blocks that are assigned to the region using the blocks interface
  if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region('content_bottom')) {
    $blocks_content_bottom = $blocks;
  }

  // Merge them together
  $vars['region']['content_bottom'] = array_merge($context_content_bottom, $blocks_content_bottom);
```

Taken from [here](http://befused.com/drupal/region-nodetpl)

but why not do it in the UI ??
just place the block several times under opposed conditions

Comment: Why not the UI!! So I'm having a dumb day. I got lost in the rabbit hole of this. Thank you for pulling me back up. Right answer: The UI! Upvote.